# Save reducers output directory path to a variable in Hadoop

Tags: variables, path, hadoop, reducers

How do I save the output path of Hadoop reducers to a variable?

This variable will be used by all other MR jobs.

These jobs will be sequential.

All the sequential MR jobs will write their corresponding output to that output directory.

I need their path variable to be updated accordingly.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but do you want all MR jobs to output to the same directory? You can't do that; the output directory for a job must be empty.

Comment: Or do you want to chain jobs together, with the output of one being the input of the next?

Comment: Are you submitting from shell or from a java program?

Comment: Hi  ajduff574, Yes one output of MR will be used as the input to the next MR job..I wanted that all the sequential MR job will write back their corresponding output to the same output directory but I found out that it is not possible so I am currently sending the previous MR output to the next MR job as an input and the first directory of the data file will be accompany with the input means two different directory path

Comment: Hi Thomas, Yes from a Java program :D

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at "Oozie". It's a Hadoop workflow engine which allows just what you described. Multiple jobs can take their "Input" as an "Output" from the last job.

There are other solutions for this such as "Cascading" API.

http://www.concurrentinc.com/products/
http://yahoo.github.com/oozie/releases/2.0.0/#Quick_Start

Comment: Thanks Jeremy but the problem is I cannot use the "Cascading" but I will try to use the Oozie. Currently I am using simple Hadoop code to solve the issue if it will not work I will use Oozie.